Changing Text color of Wrappable Table Cell when row is selected in JavaFx TableView
I was trying to wrap text for a particular table column in my TableView. I implemented the below code for that. Problem with this code is that it sets the default Text color as Black. It changes the color for other columns but not for this one. I want to change the color of this column as well when the Table Row is selected.
addressCol.setCellFactory(tc -> {
            TableCell<Customer, String> cell = new TableCell<>();
            Text text = new Text();
            text.setStyle("-fx-text-alignment: CENTER;");
            cell.setGraphic(text);
            cell.setPrefHeight(Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
            text.wrappingWidthProperty().bind(addressCol.widthProperty());
            text.textProperty().bind(cell.itemProperty());
            return cell ;
        });


This seems like an unusual way to try to accomplish this.  JavaFX cells are already descendants of Labeled, so they natively support having text without setting a graphic or using binding, and they can be styled via external CSS, including for selection handling (done in the default modena.css stylesheet).   If you stick with using the default label text, you can keep the default styling in your stylesheet or customize your stylesheet as you wish.

@jewelsea I have styled my table with stylesheet but I wanted to wrap my text for one of the columns with text.wrappingWidthProperty().bind(addressCol.widthProperty());. So, I used this way, but now it sets the default color as Black for addressCol
